# How to add a DKIM record to AWS Lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail, dkim

Most DKIM records are much longer than 255 characters. In AWS LightSail DNS tool when you go to add the TXT record it trips the error: "Each line must be between 0 and 255 characters and contain only printable ASCII characters" . There are various posts on stack overflow that indicate to solve this in AWS Route 53 you must break it into various strings. However, in AWS Route 53 you manually add this record (i.e, IN TXT "v=blahlblablh" "blah blah"). However, in was LightSail it does not let you put it in this format. You instead put the value in directly v=blahblahblah...

Therefore, you do not add quotes and if you do try to wrap it in quotes it still causes the same error. So how can you add these types of records to AWS Lightsail?????

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
https://serverfault.com/questions/763815/route-53-doesnt-allow-adding-dkim-keys-because-length-is-too-long

it works" just add two sets of "" a set to cut it and a wrapping set

Comment: This doesn't seem to be accepted by the Lightsail validation anymore. The only way I could make it work was to add a line break (no quotes were needed whatsoever). But upon checking using https://dkimvalidator.com, it still says my DKIM is invalid

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lightsail and Route 53 are different approaches for character limits in DNS records.

If you use quotation marks (" ") in Lightsail you got an error like
***"line must be between 0 and 255 characters and contain only printable ASCII characters"***

So quotation marks (" ") and space only work in **AWS Route 53**

In **AWS Lightsail** use a single new line for the separation.

My Reference: [Adding DKIM Records in AWS Lightsail](https://www.codehref.com/add-dkim-records-in-aws-lightsail/)